# Checking whether two objects being used in two arrays are the same

Tags: objective-c, arrays, if-statement

I have two arrays that include 5 pictures of a background with a solid color. This is the code used to put the images into the arrays:

```
self.colorArray = @[
                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"orange_square"],
                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"purple_square"],
                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"red_square"],
                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"blue_square"],
                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"green_square"],
                    ];
self.iconColorArray = @[
                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"orange_icon"],
                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"purple_icon"],
                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"red_icon"],
                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"blue_icon"],
                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"green_icon"],
                    ];
```

As you can see the images are respectively put in order in terms of the color of their background. (I use different images for the arrays because `iconColorArray` is being used for a smaller `UIImageView`)

The app randomly changes the images of the two `UIImageViews`.

What I want is a if-else statement to compare the two arrays to see if the same `objectAtIndex` is being used. Exp: If `orange_square` is used for one `UIImageView` and `orange_icon` is being used for the other, the condition in the if-else statement will return true.

Basically to answer my question, just tell me how I would get the index of an object being used by a `UIImageView` in a array.

Edit:
Using Matt's advice, I changed the code to:

```
NSUInteger d = [self.colorArray indexOfObject:self.squareOne.image];
NSUInteger e = [self.iconColorArray indexOfObject:self.icon.image];
```

Now, I can compare them.

Comment: Why do you say "the above code doesn't really make sense"? What doesn't make sense about it? Have you tried it? What happened when you did?

Comment: @matt Oh. Sorry. I was in a rush, and guessed what I could've done, and supposed it was wrong. I'll edit the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you get the index of an object is with (wait for it) `indexOfObject:`.

The problem is that the use of this method presupposes that this object can be compared for equality. I don't know whether UIImage does; I rather doubt it, but you can try.

Another possibility is `indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:`; this *might* work if the image is not copied by the image view but is an actual reference to one and the same image as the image in the array.

Having said all that, which would I do? None of them. I wouldn't even keep arrays of images; it's terribly wasteful of memory, and your app is likely to crash before it gets off the ground. What I would do is keep an array of the *names* of the images; strings are tiny, images are huge. And in order to make the comparison, I would subclass UIImageView to have a `name` property so that I could assign the name as well as the image, and now the problem is trivial.

Or you could even display the images through a view controller of their own, and give the view controller the `name` property. As a matter of fact I happen to have an example of doing that:

https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch06p311pageController/ch19p626pageController/Pep.swift

And in fact if you explore the rest of that project you will see that I the proceed to do exactly what you are asking to do: to learn what pep boy is being displayed, I ask the Pep object for its `boy` string and *I look up its index in a list of Pep boys*:

https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch06p311pageController/ch19p626pageController/AppDelegate.swift

It's in Swift so I use `find` instead of `indexOfObject:` but it amounts to the same thing.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I'm going to go with array, because I'm not so experienced in Objective-C. Look at my edit ^

Answer (score 0):

You could create a third object as a dictionary, where the image square names names are the keys are the keys. And then you colorArray and iconColorArray could derive from this dictionary.

```
self.imageMap = { @"orange_square" : @"orange_icon",
                  @"purple_square" : @"purple_icon" }

- (BOOL)squareUsed:(UIImage *)square isSameAsIcon:(UIImage *)iconUsed {
  for (NSString *key in self.imageMap) {
    if ([[UIImage imageNamed:key] isEqual:square]) {
      if ([UIImage imageNamed:self.imageMap[key]] isEqual:iconUsed]) {
        return YES;
      }
      // We matched the square and the icon didn't match.
      return NO;
    }
  }
  // We never matched the square. Assert?
  return NO;
}
```

Comment: Thanks I'll test it out. But isn't there like a way to extract the value of the index of a object and compare it to another?

Comment: Yes, you could extract the value. But your values at the indexes are not equivalent (unless orange_square and orange_icon are really the same image), so the comparison wouldn't work.

Comment: The images are the same. The difference is only the size

Comment: If the images are the same, why are you using different names? If you use the same name, then you can easily compare the names (or the image objects)

Comment: Because the two UIImageViews are different sizes, and constraints are in the images

Comment: If the constraints are in the images and they are not the same size, then they are not the same images (and will not create the same UIImage object). The objects in the arrays are not equivalent

Comment: Let's start over. The images in both arrays are pretty much the same. They look the same, smell the same, and feel the same. The only difference they have are the sizes of the images, which you don't need to worry about.